# How to retrieve data from a file very fast in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, sockets

I have a situation like, I am provided with a log file that consists of Strings. What I have to do is , I need to retrieve each string from the file and pass through a Socket and when the End of the File reaches it has to go again to the beginning of the file and send again the Strings. I have written a simple code using an infinite  thread that sends the strings and when the EOF comes I am closing the file and again re-opening the file using new BufferedReader object. And I am also giving a small amount of 5ms of thread sleep, but after some time my Process is entering into Pause state (Like a Dead Lock). Is there anyway to improve the speed of transfer? or else can I eliminate the Pause state.

Below is my Simple code:

```
public class Write extends Thread{

private static final String FileName = "Messages.txt";
private static final int port = 8080;
private final int time = 5;
ServerSocket  serverSocket;
Socket writeSocket;

@Override
  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port+ " ...");
            Socket writeSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected to Client : "+ writeSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());

            OutputStream outStream = writeSocket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            String str = "";
            while(true)
            {
                str = input.readLine();

              if(str==null ){
                 input.close();
                 input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            }

               else{
                System.out.println("Outgoing Message>>"+str);
                out.println(str);
                Thread.sleep(time);
               }
            }

    }
    catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Write.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }

}
```

Let me give you a simple explanation. Consider the above code is in a Server code. And when I run a client machine in the same PC, I can able to send the messages at some(high) speed but after sometime, both the client and the Server are entering into a Pause state. I feel this like a Dead Lock. The client is showing like the Server is disconnected and again Connected. When I close the Client then again Server is starting. Can anyone tell me is there a way to process the strings at a  very high speed?

Comment: Well if you want to go fast `Thread.sleep()` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Where is the client code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide you the Client code,as it is developed by other people and all they provided me a .exe file. It is a .Net client and mine is a Java Server.

Comment: Thank you markspace. If I remove the Sleep method , then both the client and server are entering into the PAUSE state within a lesser time.

Comment: 1. You can make it twice as fast by only sending the file once. 2. If you want it fast why the sleeps? 3. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: I need to send the file continuously ,when the file reaches the end it has to start again from the first. I kept the Sleep because the CPU usage can be high without a sleep. I agree with you EJP , but I want the lines to be read still fast.

Answer (score 0):

Re the program blocking, I would suggest:

1. put a `System.out.print("A")` before `out.println()` and a `System.out.print("B")` after. If it blocks with "A" as the last message in the output, then the problem is at the client side (they're not consuming the data, causing eventually the sender to block).
2. If the previous situation happens, write your own simple client which just reads data from the socket and throws it away, so you can demonstrate the problem is at the other side.

Re speed, you want to remove the `sleep` and `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use java nio to read all lines?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-
Or is the file too big to do this?

Comment: The file is not too big. It  is like a 100mb text file with very long strings in it

Answer (score 0):

your code that reads the log file is just fine. no need to make it faster.  see below (I commented the parts of the code that deal with the socket and the code works well at reading the log file multiple times. there is no sign of slowing down or deadlocks) :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Write extends Thread {

    private static final String FileName = "/tmp/Messages.txt";
    private static final int port = 8080;
    private final int time = 5;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket writeSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Write write = new Write();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Write());
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
//            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
//            System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port + " ...");
//            Socket writeSocket = serverSocket.accept();
//            System.out.println("Connected to Client : " + writeSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
//
//            OutputStream outStream = writeSocket.getOutputStream();
//            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            String str = "";
            while (true) {
                str = input.readLine();

                if (str == null) {
                    input.close();
                    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Outgoing Message>>" + str);
                    //out.println(str);
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Write.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Jose, but I need to send the strings over a socket. It is compulsory for me.

Comment: yes, I understand, but I'm trying to show that the problem is not in the handling of the log file.  if your thread is getting locked, the problem is somewhere else.  perhaps some problem with the socket, or the client is not sending any more data for example